# Android Find current location Error

Tags: android, location, position

I am working on the application to find the user location .
In my mapview I complete the task perfect.
but while finding the location I didn't get it.
below is my code and logcat error too..

Code:

```
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    mlocationManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) ;

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

    String locatinProvider = mlocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,true);

    Location mlocation = mlocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locatinProvider);

    tv.setText("Last location lat:" +mlocation.getLatitude() + "long:" + mlocation.getLongitude() );
```

LogCat:

```
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.satyam.curlocation/com.satyam.curlocation.CurLocationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 17:13:12.260: E/AndroidRuntime(1215): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: In case of a NullPointerException, the relevant lines in the LogCat are directly _below_ "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException". Please include them in your question, as they will tell us (and you) what line triggered the problem.

Comment: Thank Paul for managing properly my question.

Comment: To avoid this type "will I have to  start debugging into the Device instead of Emulator ?"
please guide me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` returns null if there is no last location available or provider is disabled. See [the manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29).

```
Location mlocation = mlocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locatinProvider);

if(mlocation != null){
    tv.setText("Last location lat:" +mlocation.getLatitude() + "long:" + mlocation.getLongitude() );
}else{
    tv.setText("No last location available");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

register your **MapActivity** class under **Activity**  in **Android ManifestFile.xml**